# C++ Crash on a non-void function doesn't have return statement

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk

I got a crash when a non void function like this doesn't return anything:

```
#include <iostream>

    class ClassA {
    public:
        bool foo();
        void foo2();
    };
    bool ClassA::foo() {
        int var1 = 100;
        var1++; 
    }
    
    void ClassA::foo2() {
       foo();
    }
    
    int main() {
       ClassA a;
       a.foo2();
       printf("end of code");
       return 0;
    }
```

Note that the return type of foo() is bool but implementation doesn't return anything. The crash is 100% reproducible on Android NDK-version r19.

Also same code works fine on NDK-r15c.

Comment: So you have a crash, normally this is caused by a bug in your code. Why do you think that it's caused by this issue, what evidence do you have?

Comment: You'll need to show us a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @john Because when I put a return statement the crash is gone. And I have tried changing the code at many places. So it shouldn't be case of dangling pointer etc

Comment: see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/153374

Comment: @PaulEvans I could do that. But I am asking if anybody is aware of this kind of issue already.

Comment: @Chipster Interesting that the behaviour is different in C, and it seem to be the C like behaviour that the OP is expecting.

Comment: @Chipster I think if you use the return value then its an undefined behavior. But if you are not using the return value, there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: @user18853 As the link explains (no idea if it's accurate or not) that's the rules for C, but not C++.

Comment: "I think if you use the return value then its an undefined behavior."  Incorrect.  It is undefined behavior even if the return value is not used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I got a crash when a non void function like this didn't return anything:

Because this is Undefined Behavior.

§8.6.3 of the draft C++20 standard:

> flowing off the end of a [non-void] function other than main
>   results in undefined behavior.

Note that this is unrelated to how the function is actually called. So even when the return value is ignored (as in the case of the OP), it's the "flowing off the end" that results in UB.

Comment: Very true. And here is more info on this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43943

Comment: Correct. In the current draft, but also the same in every standard since 1998.

Comment: Can you point out in your answer that not only using the return value is undefined behavior. But returning nothing will also cause undefined behavior. Although above statement from §8.6.3 is sufficient, but mentioning again will stress this out more. This was the original confusion at the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You are [invoking Undefined Behavior](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/153374):

> If a function is declared to return a value, and fails to do so, the result is undefined behavior (in C++). One possible result is seeming to work, which is pretty much what you're seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your program was always broken.

The function *must* have a `return`, and your compiler should have warned you about this.

In C++, whether you use the resulting value at the callsite is irrelevant (though this isn't the case in C).

It is just that you got unlucky with previous toolchains that *just so happened* to produce code that *just so happened* not to cause a crash as its symptom. That's unlucky because it would have prompted you to correct the bug at the time.